# $request not working on laravel get method

Tags: php, laravel, get, routes

I have a route

```
Route::get('student-search', 'Students@search')
```

and url on browser

```
student-search?session=2&name=raj&grade=1&section=a
```

But while returning `$request` its returning empty . Same thing is working fine on local but not working after trnsferring it to server.

code of search function looks like this

```
public function search(Request $request){
        return $request;
...
```

and $request returns empty . While same thing is working on localhost.

Comment: Please show us the code for your `search` function.

Comment: In which file is that "search" function implemented?

Comment: see my answer @salin kunvar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are missing is your server is not passing query parameter in any form of request. If you are using nginx try

```
location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;                
           }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:-

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request; // add this in top controller
public function search(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->all();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);
}

   ------OR--------

use Request; // add this in top controller
public function search() {
    $data = Request::all();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That's something that really bothers me: You can "use" that Request, but you can also "use" the Request of the Facades. I never know which one I need.